# How can I use the store of Pinia in the child VueJS application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, pinia

I am creating a library to reuse a VueJS app in several other projects. It's a plugin to generate and display forms in any VueJS project.

I use pinia for the store in this library & Vite to build it. How can I make the library's store readable at the project level that imports it?
My problem is that in the chrome extension for VueJS I don't have access to this store.

Example in the library I created this store in my library:
[image: Screen print of the store initialization]

In the `main.ts` file I have the `install` method:

```js
export default {
  install: (app: App, options: PluginOptions) => {
    app.component('UsfBuilder', UsfBuilder)

    app.use(createPinia())
  },
}
```

... but in my Vue extension I only see the app stores, and I don't see the store of the library ...
[image: Screen print of the VueJS dev tools]

I know it works because when I use "console.log" in the library store, the state elements are displayed with the good values!
[image: Screen print of the conole tab in the chrome inspector]

Stack:

- VueJS: 3.2.41
- Pinia: 2.0.23
- Vite: 2.9.15

Comment: The library possibly uses a different copy of Pinia. The question needs to have more details

Comment: ok, how can I make sure I use the same instance?

Comment: Can't say without knowing the case. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. If this library is imported from a separate package, `pinia` should  be in its peerDependencies, so there would be only one `pinia` in node_modules

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found the solution! (see below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to reddit. If you build a library with Pina, in the `vite.config.ts` file you have to add `Pinia` option in the `rollupOptions` in `external` & `globals`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  //...
build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      esmExternals: true,
    },
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.ts'),
      name: 'Formbuilder',
      fileName: 'formbuilder-plugin',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue', 'pinia'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue',
          pinia: 'pinia',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```